# Put heading on top of Responsive image without Flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I want to put a heading on top of an image, vertically and horizontally center aligned. I've achieved it through Flexbox. However, some browsers are not supporting Flexbox. Is there is any way to do it without flexbox?

[image]

Note: The image must be responsive. So I can't use background image for div

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-6 category" @click="openPopup('cement')">
  <img src="https://www.quotzap.com/static/images/categories/cement.jpg" width="100%" />
  <h2>Cement</h2>
</div>

.category{
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  justify-content: center;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.category h2{
  max-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.category img{
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(143,143,143,0.68);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your CSS to this... if you dont want to use flex box.

```
.category{
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 0;
}
.category h2{
  max-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:50%;
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  z-index:2;
}
.category img{
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(143,143,143,0.68);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

Comment: No worries... Glad it sorted your issue.